# Should I consider Reflection

Tags: c#

I'm not really sure, when I should consider not use reflection.
At the moment I struggling with the following scenario:

A mapping  between two classes are done by reflection (with dictionary to property).
In one class we have a `dictionary<string, object>` and in the other class we have properties with the same name as the key of the dictionary. Then I sue reflection to get the property and set it.

You see, there are also costly castings of all the objects. And sometimes I must do a custom cast, because the types are diffrent..

The only big advantage of the reflection is the 'easy' mapping with few lines and less classes. Both Reflection and the normal property set approach is possible.

> **NOTE**: My question is more from the perspective of design, rather of 'how to' solve the problem.

It would be appreciated if you can give me some advices.

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing a wheel, squared. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), maybe?

Comment: It sounds like you have already have, considering the fact you have already implemented a solution with it. I think you should consider [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: You're going to need to give more details about the actual underlying problem.  That specific task can only be done with reflection, but there may be a way of solving the underlying problem without needing to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is more from a perspective of design, rather of `how to` solve the problem

To answer your question, in general you would use Reflection to do dynamic property mappings like this. However, in practise Reflection can be heavy & slow (as you are beginning to notice). As you have probably guessed this problem is pretty common and there are already libraries out there that do all the heavy lifting for you e.g. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

As far as mapping a `Dictionary` to an object is concerned, I have never used AutoMapper for something like that therefore I couldn't comment on whether it would support it or not (my guess it it probably could, it's pretty flexible). If your `Dictionary` is just a bridge for your custom mapping then if you did switch to using `AutoMapper` you could get rid of this completely.